# Does the Black's equation work for immortal wires / interconnections (or only for mortal ones)?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I'm trying to understand whether the [Black's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%27s_equation) is only true for mortal wire / interconnections or it is also applicable to immortal wires (essentially when its $jL$ product is less than $jL_{blech}$ where $j$ and $L$ are the current density and the length of the wire respectively).

Thanks,

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what a mortal/immortal  wire is. Can you give a link?

Comment: @annav Refer to the section "wire length" http://www.synopsys.com/Tools/Verification/CapsuleModule/CustomSim-RA-wp.pdf

Comment: thanks, but  completely out of my data base. I think this should be asked in the electronics.stackexchange if it gets no response here.

Comment: "immortal" is not a technical term.  I think you are asking "why does electromigration not effect wires shorter than the [Blech length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration#Blech_length)?"  (To which I do not, unfortunately, know the answer.)

Comment: @WanderingLogic Thanks for contribution, but what I am asking is, whether the Black's equation gives a correct Mean Time To Failure (MTTF) estimation for the wires which do not suffer from electromigration (e.i. the wires with the $jL$ product smaller than $jL_{blech}$).

Comment: Black's equation contains no component based on wire length, so no.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not an expert on electromigration, it seems obvious to me that the answer is "Black's equation does not apply to very short wires".

- [Black's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%27s_equation) is an empirical model to estimate the MTTF (mean time to failure) of a wire due to electromigration. The equation does not mention length, and so it predicts the same MTTF no matter what the length of the wire.
- Wikipedia says of the [Blech length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration#Blech_length) "Any wire that has a length below this limit will not fail by electromigration."
- Black's equation predicts that even very short wires will fail due to electromigration, which contradicts the discovery of Mr. Bleck that such wires actually don't fail due to electromigration.

Therefore

- Black's equation doesn't apply to wires shorter than the Blech length.

My understanding is that Black's equation is a very useful and practical rule of thumb that was used long before anyone understood the physical mechanisms of eletromigration, and is still used today.
Much like Newton's second law ("F=ma") is still used today, even though "F=ma" is known to be incorrect over very small distances or at very high velocities.

R.L. de Orio et. al. have have developed physics-based models to estimate MTTF of a wire.
As you might have expected, those models give approximately the same MTTF as Black's equation for long wires in the kind of environment Mr. Black worked in, and a much longer MTTF ("immortal") for very short wires.

R.L. de Orio, H. Ceric, S. Selberherr.
["Physically based models of electromigration: From Black’s equation to modern TCAD models"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F220456802_Physically_based_models_of_electromigration_From_Black%27s_equation_to_modern_TCAD_models%2Ffile%2Fd912f50f5ceeeb4bb4.pdf&ei=kmflUeyiAYmayAGuhYH4Dw&usg=AFQjCNGOSqdlvcvIk_KkuUx1Oio5WRl96Q&sig2=nbP39VHlkxbiVHd9LBsryg&bvm=bv.48705608,d.aWc)
Microelectronics Reliability journal.
2010.